# Certain chords of a parameterized parabola pass through a common point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> If the end points $P(t_1)$ and $Q (t_2)$ of a chord of a parabola with parameterization $(at^2, 2at)$ satisfy the relation $t_1t_2 = k$ (constant) then we have to find the fixed point through which chord will always pass.

I tried

I wrote the equation of chord i.e $2x - (t_1+ t_2) + 2at_1t_2 = 0$

After putting $t_2= \frac{t_1}{k}$

I got $2x -t_1y - k(\frac{y}{t_1} -2a) = 0$

But how do I will get the fixed point.

Comment: What are $t_1$ and $t_2$ ? Are they the abcissa of points P and Q? Are they the ordinate of P and Q ? Or something else ?

Comment: @JJacquelin  They way of denoting a point on parabola for example  P(t) means the coordinate of p are (at^2, 2at)

Answer (score 2):

The chord joining the points $P'(-t_1), Q'(-t_2)$ must also pass through this fixed point, so by symmetry the fixed point has $y=0$ and therefore the coordinates are $$(-ka, 0)$$

Note that in the special case where $k=-1$ the fixed point is the focus $(a, 0)$

Answer (score 0):

If the parameterization of the parabola is $\left(\frac{t^2}{4a},t\right)$, then the coordinates of $P$ and $Q$ will be $\left(\frac{t_1^2}{4a},t_1\right)$ and $\left(\frac{t_2^2}{4a},t_2\right)$, respectively, and the chord will lie on the line $$y-t_1=\frac{t_2-t_1}{\frac{t_2^2}{4a}-\frac{t_1^2}{4a}}\cdot\left(x-\frac{t_1^2}{4a}\right).$$
This simplifies to $y=\frac{4ax-t_1^2}{t_2+t_1}+t_1$ and substituting $t_2=\frac{k}{t_1}$ allows for the form $$y=\frac{t_1\left(4ax+k\right)}{k+t_1^2},$$
which implies the fixed point is $$\left(-\frac{k}{4a},0\right),$$ rather than $$\left(-ka,0\right).$$

Comment: In your parameterization, $t_1t_2=4a^2k$.